# Python - Regex find string and get x letters - escape doesnt work

Tags: python, regex

So with following im adding Script from a webpage to a dict and afterwards trying to find a certain string in it, then get the 13 letters after:

```
for link in productlinks:
    try:
        s = HTMLSession()
        r = s.get(link)
        response = urllib3.PoolManager().request(
            "GET", link, headers={'User-Agent': "python"})
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.data.decode('utf-8'), 'html.parser')
        title = r.html.find('h1.rd-title', first=True).text
        script2 = []
        script1 = soup.findAll("script")[2]
        script2.append(script1)
        special_string = '"ean",values:[{text:"'
        x_letters_afterwards = 13
        result = re.findall(re.escape(special_string) + ".{" + x_letters_afterwards + "}", script2)
        print(result)
    except:
        print("...")
```

The problem is the for loop try seems to break to an except through something as it always just prints "..." instead of the string i try to extract (or something else in general).

An example of the output where the string should be found: https://pastebin.com/xvzQ456P

I dont know what to do...

Comment: Replace `special_string` with `re.escape(special_string)` in the `re.findall` call. There are special regex metacharacters in `special_string`, you need to have them escaped.

Comment: i did still no change

Comment: i also tried it with json, with json the same happens

Comment: Ok, the regex approach does not work because `script2` is a list of ... why are you using `script2` as an input to `re.findall`? `script1` is a node, and if it contains the `script` data, use this instead, `re.findall(re.escape(special_string) + "(.{13})", ' '.join([x for x in script1]))`

Comment: yes except it always prints with brackets and '' even with .replace or .split

Comment: its also not a dictionary i know because i tried to convert to string but it still printed with brackets

Comment: Ok, I see. So, it works. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Your `script2` is a list of objects. You need to get the string and pass it to the `re` method.

However, you are using `re.findall` that fetches a *list* of matches. You need to use `re.search` to get the first match only:

```py
special_string = '"ean",values:[{text:"'
x_letters_afterwards = 13
match = re.search(re.escape(special_string) + "(.{" + x_letters_afterwards + "})", ' '.join([x for x in script1]))
result = ''
if match:
    result = match.group(1)
```

Notes:

- `re.escape(special_string)` - `re.escape` appends a `\` escape before each special regex char in the `special_string` string that is used literally in the regex
- `"(.{" + x_letters_afterwards + "})"` will form a capturing group (with ID = 1) that will ook like `(.{13})` and will *capture* any 13 chars other than line break chars into Group 1
- You need to check if there is a match first, before accessing the group value, hence, `if match:` check
- Once the check if positive, there is a match, the Group 1 value from `match.group(1)` is assigned to `result`.